# How to remember a position in a texarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, textarea

I just want to remember always the last position in a textarea, but I fail always.

I've got this code:

```
//This function catch the position

(function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);

    //Insert the text by clicking an icon

function insertar(texto) {

  var div = $('textarea');     
  var text = div.val();
  var pos = div.getCursorPosition();
  text = text.substring(0,pos) + " " + texto + text.substring(pos);
  div.val(text);

}

$('#icon').click(function(evt){ insertar(':icon:'); });
```

Well, if I write this:

"hello hello"

And I want to add this with the function:

"hi hi hello hello"

It give me this:

"hi hello hello hi."

I think the second time I execute the function, this forget the position and add the text at the end of the text.

PD: I'm adding text clicking on an image. I'm trying to do a quick reply fieldset for a forum.

Anyone knows where the problem is?

Here is my demo where you can see it: http://jsfiddle.net/ko295zpw/6/

Comment: so you mean you want to insert text in front ? .. like this http://jsfiddle.net/ko295zpw/8/

Comment: [selectionEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Comment: Nope, Dave. I want to click once at the beggining or another position and add as text as I want leaving the rest of the text in its position. Just like a quick reply editor that you can find in any forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set a bool that determines whether or not you need to re-find the cursor position, then reset the bool to true every time the `textarea` is clicked and set it to false after you've found the position the first time after the user has clicked on the `textarea`.  You'd need to move the declarations of both `var pos` and the bool to a scope outside the `insertar` function.  So:

```
var encontrarPos = true;
var pos = 0;
function insertar(texto) {

    var div = $('textarea');     
    var text = div.val();
    if (encontrarPos) pos = div.getCursorPosition();
    encontrarPos = false;
    console.log(pos);
    text = text.substring(0,pos) + texto + " " + text.substring(pos);
    div.val(text);

}

$('textarea').click(function() {
    encontrarPos = true;
});
```

And here's the updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/ko295zpw/11/)

Comment: That's a good idea, indeed it solve the 50% of the problem, because generate other more xD

It will be wonderful to know how add more once you have added something, respecting the order.

Comment: Solved. I've added this to your code at the end of the function insertar, bowheart:

pos = post + texto.length + 1;